# Using Wget on angular website

Tags: angularjs, wget

I am using Wget to download a page from an angular website which requires a login.

The command I am using is

```
wget.exe --no-check-certificate --http-user=USERNAME --http-password=PASSWORD --output-document=.\\output\\output.html http://example.com/view/details/884484
```

But this results in only the index.html page being downloaded. The authorization works OK so I know that is not the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular uses client side routing. All paths in an app beyond the root of the app that are requested at server get sent the index.html of the app root. 
Then angular router determines templates and content based on url client side.

That is the nature of all [single page applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

You would need to use a headless browser to run the javascript in the app if you want content from within it

Comment: Thank you, I will look into using phantomjs instead of wget.